# Way to convert a list of dataframes to a list of character vectors in r?

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I  have a list like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLT1L.png I want the list to be a character vectors not a list of list with values as tibbles how do I convert the whole list?  I need to retain the grouping.  I did groupsplit  to get to where I am in dplyr

[image]

```
f.vars.h1.list<-f.vars.to.agg.1h%>%
  group_split(ActivityGroup, keep = FALSE)

$`Fans`
[2] "Shea""Fenway"                 
[4] "Mets" "Eagles"  

$`Spicy`
character(0)

$`Trays`
[2] "Yankeess"             
[4] "Wildcard" "Patriots"         
[7] "teams"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question with the output of `dput(f.vars.to.agg.1h)`?

Comment: how do I accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the other column from where you want to split the values in `f.vars.to.agg.1h` called? For simplicity assuming here it is called as `col` you could use `base::split`.

```
f.vars.h1.list <- split(f.vars.to.agg.1h$col, f.vars.to.agg.1h$ActivityGroup)
```

If you want to continue using `tidyverse` `group_split` always returns a tibble you can `unlist` the output :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

f.vars.h1.list <- f.vars.to.agg.1h %>%
  group_split(ActivityGroup, keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(unlist)
```